# Apollo Graphql: Rename schema for backward compatibility

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, express-graphql

**What I want do ?**

In Apollo Graphl server, I want to change an entity  `Person` to `Human` in schema but i don't want to break my clients (frontend that are querying graphql).  So if client is making query for `Person` i want to map it to `Human`.

**Example:**

**CLIENT QUERY**

`query  {
  Person {
    ID
    firstName
  }
}`

**REWRITE TO**

`query  {
  Human {
    ID
    name
  }
}`

**REWRITE THE RESPONSE**

`{
 data: {
  Person: {
  Id: 123,
  name:"abc"
}
}
}`

**Things that I have tried**

[graphql-rewriter](https://github.com/ef-eng/graphql-query-rewriter) provides something similar to what i am looking for. I went through it documentation but it doesn't have the option to rewrite the field name.

In apollo graphql documentation [Apollow graphql directives](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives/), They have mentioned about rename directive but i did not find `rename-directive-package` the node module.

[apollo-directives-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-directives-package) I have tried this as well but it doesn't have the option to rename the scaler field e.g

```js
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";
import { RenameDirective } from "rename-directive-package";

const typeDefs = `
type Person @rename(to: "Human") {
  name: String!
  currentDateMinusDateOfBirth: Int @rename(to: "age")
}`;

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  schemaDirectives: {
    rename: RenameDirective
  }
});
```

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here i hope this gives helps you, first we have to create the schema-directive

```
import { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from "graphql-tools";
import { GraphQLObjectType, defaultFieldResolver } from "graphql";

/**
 * 
 */
export class RenameSchemaDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {GraphQLObjectType} obj 
     */
    visitObject(obj) {
        const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = obj;


        obj.name = this.args.to;
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

**type-defs.js**

```
directive @rename(to: String!) on OBJ

type AuthorizedUser @rename(to: "Human1") {
    id: ID!
    token: ID!
    fullName: String!
    roles: [Role!]!
  }
```